# build a table in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, getfeatureinfo

I want to create a table filled with information from an external source. I found a solution on the internet, but I want to change the view of the table. I can now build this table:

[image: table]

with this code:

```
function showInfo(evt) {
    var f = 0;
    var temstr = "";
    if(evt.features.length != 0){
        for (f = 0; f <= evt.features.length - 1; f++) {
            if(evt.features[f].gml.featureType == "amice_om_herk"){
                temstr = temstr + "<b>" + "<center>Herkomstlocatie</center>" + "</b>";
                temstr = temstr + "<table>";
                for ( var key in evt.features[f].attributes) {
                    temstr += "<tr>";
                    switch (key){
                    case 'afvlstrnum':
                        temstr += "<td width= 71px>Afvalstroomnummer</td><td>"
                        + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                        break;
                    case 'strnm_herk':
                        temstr += "<td width= 71px>Straat</td><td>"
                        + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                        break;
                    case 'hsnum_herk':
                        temstr += "<td width= 71px>Huisnummer</td><td>"
                        + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                        break;
                    case 'numtv_herk':
                        temstr += "<td width= 71px>Nummer toevoeging</td><td>"
                        + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                        break;
                    case 'plts_herk':
                        temstr += "<td width= 71px>Plaatsnaam</td><td>"
                        + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                        break;

                    default:
                    };
                    temstr += "</tr>";
                }
                temstr = temstr + "</table>";
            };

        }
        log(temstr, true);
    } else {
        log("<b>Informatie</b><br/>" + "Niets gevonden op deze locatie", true);
    }
}
```

But I want my table to look more like this:

[image: New table]

In other words, flip my table with column names above the values instead of in the row of the value. What also might be a problem, is that if I click somewhere where there are multiple values on top of each other, I want the values underneath each other but keep one column name (like the picture above), and not like this:

[image]

Could someone help me with this? I'm not an experienced coder.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the best question for Stackoverflow (hence the down votes), but I can point you in the right direction.

Basically, you need to start the table `<table>`, then create a row with `<tr>` and create your table headings in it with the `<th>` tag.

Once you have your heading, then use the `for` loop above to populate the table with data.

Also, you can refer to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headers) to see examples of Horizontal and Vertical headings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i dont want to do the whole coding for you, thats why i write something like an api that may help you:

```
function grid(columnNames){
this.rows=[];
this.columnNames=columnNames;
this.addRow=function(row){
//add to the rows array
this.rows.push(row);
}
this.render=function(){
html="<table><tr>";
//loop trough the headings first
 this.columnNames.forEach(function(column){
html+="<th>"+column+"</th>";
});
html+="</tr>";
//loop trough the rows
this.rows.forEach(function(row){
html+="<tr>";
//loop trough columns
row.forEach(function(col){
html+="<td>"+col+"</td>";
});
html+="</tr>";

});
html+="</table>";
return html;
};
}
```

Use like this:

```
newgrid=new grid(["column a","column b"]);
newgrid.addRow(["value a1","value b1"]);
newgrid.addRow(["value a2", "value b2"]);
document.all.body.innerHTML=newgrid.render();
```